# Automatically logout off web page Aurelia MVC5 authentication on ExpireTimeSpan

Tags: javascript, c#, authentication, logoff, cookie-authentication

I have an MVC5 ".Net Framework 4.6.2" web sever with Aurelia SPA that works perfectly fine. What I am looking to do, is to extend my authentication to auto-logout the user after a period of inactivity.

With the CookieAuthenticationOptions setup as follows

```
LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
SlidingExpiration=true,
ExpireTimeSpan=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)
```

What happens is, the user is no longer authenticated after the ExpireTimeSpan is reached, which is expected, but they are not automatically redirected to the Loginpath which what I need to happen.

I have the basic Startup class as seen below but the cookie ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie" never expires, it is set to 1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            //ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120),
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try to set in webconfig?

Comment: Do you mean like <sessionState timeout="120" cookieless="AutoDetect">? Yes I tried this and can get it to logout but this is not what I am trying to achieve.